# Run servoblaster Python code

Tags: python, servo

lately i installed servoblaster to my raspberry pi and then tried a simple python code `

```
import os
import time

os.system('sudo ./servod')

while True:
    os.system("echo 1=100 > /dev/servoblaster")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("echo 1=1 > /dev/servoblaster")
    time.sleep(2)
```

i put the code in the directory of servoblaster `/home/pi/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user/file1.py` but when run `sudo python file1.py` this what i got

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user $ sudo python file1.py
Board model:                     2
GPIO configuration:            P1 (40 pins)
Using hardware:                PWM
Using DMA channel:              14
Idle timeout:             Disabled
Number of servos:                8
Servo cycle time:            20000us
Pulse increment step size:      10us
Minimum width value:            50 (500us)
Maximum width value:           250 (2500us)
Output levels:              Normal

Using P1 pins:               7,11,12,13,15,16,18,22

Servo mapping:
     0 on P1-7           GPIO-4
     1 on P1-11          GPIO-17
     2 on P1-12          GPIO-18
     3 on P1-13          GPIO-27
     4 on P1-15          GPIO-22
     5 on P1-16          GPIO-23
     6 on P1-18          GPIO-24
     7 on P1-22          GPIO-25

Invalid width specified
Invalid width specified
Invalid width specified
Invalid width specified
Invalid width specified
Invalid width specified
Invalid width specified
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid width specified

See https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster

Generally a servo will expect pulse widths in the range 1000 to 2000 microseconds although some will go between 500 to 2500.

`os.system("echo 1=100 > /dev/servoblaster")`

sets 1000µs which should be okay.

`os.system("echo 1=1 > /dev/servoblaster")`

sets 10µs which will be invalid.